# Implementing a loading animation with dynamic jQuery ajax tabs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tabs

This would probably be easier to explain if I showed my code, then explained what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({ spinner: 'Retrieving data...' });
    $(".tabButton").live("click", function(){
        var getTopicID = $('.topicID',$(this).parent()).val();
                $("#tabs").tabs("remove",1);
                $("#tabs").tabs("remove",1);
        tabs.tabs('add', 'ajax.php?section=summary&id=' + getTopicID, 'Summary');
        tabs.tabs('add', 'ajax.php?section=read&id=' + getTopicID, 'Read Topic');
    });
    $(".tabButton").click(function(){
        $(".liSelected").removeClass("liSelected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("liSelected");
    });
});
```

The important line is this:

```
tabs.tabs('add', 'ajax.php?section=read&id=' + getTopicID, 'Read Topic');
```

As you can see from the inital line of code, I'm using a spinner, but I'd like a more obvious indication that the PDF is loading (some of them are quite large in size and could take a good few seconds to display, depending on the end user's connection speed).

My ideal look would be something like this: [loading gif](http://media.photobucket.com/image/loading%20animation/betchy24/loading_animation.gif), however I haven't the faintest idea how I can implement that into my code above.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I should state that I'd like the spinner to appear in the tab where the PDF will be loaded, NOT in the tab button up top.**

**further edit:** ok, so I've got it working to a certain point, but not quite as I'd like it:

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({ spinner: "", select: function(event, ui) { var tabID = "#ui-tabs-" + (ui.index + 2); $(tabID).html("<img src=/design/img/progressBar.gif />"); } });
```

So this adds a progress bar in the tab panel, but I'm unable to wrap the img tag in any block-level elements to center it as this completely breaks the tabs functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work for you.  Take advantage of the `select` and `load` events of the tabs plugin to achieve what you want.  To answer the last question in your edit, create a new div and use absolute/relative positioning on it and append it to the content area.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with

```
spinner: '<img src="loading_animation.gif" />'
```

Note from the jquery website

> An span element must be present in the A tag of the title, for the spinner content to be visible.

Of course since your using "Retrieving data..." I suspect you've already done so.  By placing the image in the spinner option it'll make it appear next to the tab and that image is fairly big so that could be a problem.

---

Another option is to take advantage of the tabs plugin `select` and `load` event

**The select Event**

Triggered when a tab is clicked

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

or Bind to the select event by type: tabsselect.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

**The load Event**

Triggered after the content of a remote tab has been loaded.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   load: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

or Bind to the load event by type: tabsload.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsload", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

You can then append the loading image into an absolute positioned div inside your content area on `tabclick` and use `tabload` to remove the div once the content is loaded.